# Stats t-test for soccer data

Tags: t-test, statsmodels

I am new to stats and had the following question

I am studying if the total number of fouls in a soccer game increases/decreases if a particular team is winning at half time. This is what I did (one sample t-test).

1. Took 5 years of data and found its mean and std. dev of fouls in a game (includes matches where the result was a draw or either team was wining at HT i.e. all possible combination of results)
2. Now, I took 100 random results (these are 100 from the above data set itself) but here I took only results where either team was winning.
   I found the std.dev, mean and t-value.

I have few questions here:
1. I am assuming point two above as the treated population. Here the treatment is; if a team is losing there is a psychological effect on the person/team which probably increases the chances of committing a foul. Does this make sense?
2. The random points(100) that I selected above are points from the same 5 years data. Is that OK? or the data points should be from a different season/matches which are not included in the 5 year data sample I have.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Ace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am studying if the total number of fouls in a soccer game increases/decreases if a particular team is winning at half time. This is what I did (one sample t-test).

"number of fouls" is count data. It's not suitable for a one-sample t-test. The distribution will tend to have variance that changes with mean and also somewhat skew. The number of fouls per match may be high enough that the discreteness doesn't matter much, but you may want to worry about different variances.

> Now, I took 100 random results

Why only 100?

> I have few questions here: 1. I am assuming point two above as the treated population. Here the treatment is; if a team is losing there is a psychological effect on the person/team which probably increases the chances of committing a foul. Does this make sense?

You should probably be comparing losing vs winning (or perhaps losing vs not-losing; or winning vs not-winning); you should avoid having the same matches in both.

You presumably want to make inference about a population other than just the data you have, so don't treat the data you have as a population.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me and commenting on my post. I will take your points into consideration and look at the data again. Greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: I had a follow-up question; you said count data is not suitable for t-test. Can you please throw some more light on it. I am not sure if I understood that correctly

Comment: A t-test comes with assumptions. Count data doesn't satisfy those assumptions, and usually won't nearly-satisfy them well enough for it to make a good approximation, though in some circumstances it may not do too badly. If you have many counts per observation (with soccer fouls I assume you're looking at averages of say 20 or more per game) many sets of counts (which you have), and without much variation in fouls (this I don't know). So in your case the failure of the assumptions may not do so badly; you could consider Welch-type t-tests to account for the heteroscedasticity. ... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... If I was (for some reason) to do use a t-test, I'd be inclined to use simulation to check it's suitability (e.g. *does the t-test have close to a t-distribution when the null hypothesis is true and the data is like the data you have?*). But there are already quite suitable, relatively simple and widely understood procedures even better suited to the kind of data you have available, so the effort of checking whether the failure of assumptions matters seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I want to second what Glen_B said.

In terms of the causal pathway you're suggesting, don't you need to focus on second half fouls? Fouls in the first half can't be due to a psychological reaction to the half time score.

Preferably those second half fouls should be compared to an appropriate baseline that takes some account of team/opponent/referee; even comparison vs first half fouls would be better than nothing.

Remember that "losing at half time" is basically a proxy for "being the weaker team". If you do find teams losing at half time tend to foul more, to some extent that's telling you that weaker teams foul more (not unexpected if that's part of a game plan to stop more skillful players) rather than what you're interested in. So you do need to do *something* that controls for team (and opposition) quality.

And it will be essentially impossible to identify a specifically *psychological* effect. You have no way of telling if the effect is purely *tactical* for instance - also plausible, since fouls are often the product of defensive desperation. A team that is behind in a match is likely under more defensive pressure anyway, and if they are attempting to get a goal back then it's reasonable to think defenders may be more likely to be left without adequate cover and so forced into committing a foul. I'm not saying that is the *correct* interpretation of any pattern in fouling, just that you can't jump to the conclusion of it being psychological unless you have some way to distinguish this from other effects with the data you have available. Underlying issues of causation are more subtle than you're giving credit for.

Comment: your argument makes sense to me. Thank you for throwing some light on it. I will consider your points and come up with a better hypothesis. I am very naive in this field but at the same time eager to learn. Greatly appreciate your inputs!

Comment: While playing in the first half can't be done with the knowledge of the half-time score, the score at half time may have been generated quite early in the game. Even if the exact half-time score was attained later in the first half, the losing team may well have been losing since almost the start (you might be 0-2 at half time but have been 0-1 since the three minute mark, for example). If you're behind at half time, on average you'll likely have been behind about half of the first half, perhaps a little more for a 0-2 (rare at half time compared to 0-1), a little less for a 1-3 (rarer still).

Comment: @Glen_b Yes this is quite correct - I actually thought about discussing this in my answer but decided against it since it seemed at the time to be a secondary issue. On reflection perhaps I should have brought this more to the forefront: in particular, is the OP more interested in the theory that *teams commit fouls at a greater rate if they are behind in the game* or (as their post suggests, but perhaps this is due to data limitations rather than what they are truly interested in) *teams that are behind at half time commit fouls at a greater rate in the second half*?

Comment: @Glen_b Agreed with your argument and I thought about that point as well.

Comment: As @Silverfish mentioned my data is not that comprehensive to carry out a very accurate analysis. It would be wise to tweak my theory a bit or analyze something that is in line with the data points that I have. Greatly appreciate inputs from both